# extract existing files from opportunities and send as an attachment in email

Tags: apex, email, content

I have changed the SF file setting by checking the ‘Files uploaded to the Attachments….’ checkbox.
Loaded a file called test.pdf  to an opportunity and noticed the title no longer contains the extension (‘.pdf’).

How can I attach the test.pdf file to an email?
I am able to loop through the content objects using :

```
 for (ContentDocumentLink docLinks : [Select Id from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = :currentOppId ]) { 
     for (ContentDocument docs : [Select Id, FileType, Title from ContentDocument where ContentDocumentId = :docLinks]) {
     }
  }
```

Code that used to work:

```
    List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new    List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
 for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :currentOppId and (Name = 'test.pdf')]){
    // Add to attachment file list  
    Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
    efa.setFileName(a.Name); 
    efa.setBody(a.Body); 
    fileAttachments.add(efa);
 }
 mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
```

Comment: Can you check if any ContentVersion exists for that document

Comment: Yes, 1 record exists in the ContentVersion for that document.

Comment: you could read from ContentVersion record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do the below changes : -

1. query was right need to do in ContentDocumentLink.
2. Need to change the second query , that query need to done in ContentVersion like belwo : -

   SELECT ContentDocumentId,VersionData,FileExtension,FileType,Id,Title FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId = : //your content document Id from upper query

where you can find your file Name from Title and extension from FileType.
And most important thing the body will stores in **VersionData**.

In your second portion of code no need to query in attachment.

In your second query put the below block : -

```
 List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new    List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
 for (This should be our second query and for loop will be done in ContentVersion){
    // Add to attachment file list  
    Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
    efa.setFileName(a.Title); //Title of the PDF
    efa.setBody(a.VersionData); //Body of the PDF,need to do transfer into blob
    fileAttachments.add(efa);
 }
 mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!! The versionData was the key!
My queries were slightly off. Below is the code that works:

```
 List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
    for (ContentDocumentLink docLinks : [Select Id, ContentDocumentId  from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = :currentOppId ]) { 
       for (ContentDocument docs : [Select Id, FileType, Title, FileExtension from ContentDocument where Id= :docLinks.ContentDocumentId and Title in ('Funding Memo','PSA') ]) {
           for (ContentVersion docVersion : [Select Id, VersionData from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId =:docLinks.ContentDocumentId ]) {

               Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();

               fileName = docs.Title.Trim() + '.' + docs.FileExtension.Trim();
               efa.setFileName(fileName); //Title of the PDF
               efa.setBody(docVersion.VersionData); //Body of the PDF,need to do transfer into blob
               fileAttachments.add(efa);
           }
       }
    }
```